# issue in displaying content via xhtml file in UIwebview in epub reader

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, epub

I have found some issues when I was trying to display some content using XHTML file.

When I load the ePub file in UIWebview for first time it is loaded proper. the First page / cover page, but when I pop to my previous view and load again another ePub file, the Cover page remains the same. Even though the cover image is extracted  and is proper.

The same url is shown proper in my MAC browser but it is not getting changed in uiwebview.

I have released the webview in `viewdidDisappear`, still not getting the issue.

Does any had the same issue? or any solution for this, please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem and after allot of wasted time, I found the cover Image is cashed; You can easily solve the problem by changing the name of the cover photo inside the epub, I used a unique name for each cover photo.